# Java ObjectInputStream reading from different Application

Tags: java, class, serialization, objectinputstream

I saved an `ArrayList<MyClass>` as object with an `ObjectOutputStream`. Now, how can I read that object on my another application project with a `ObjectInputStream`? I tried and it throws an `ClassNotFoundException`. I have copied `MyClass` from project 1 to project 2. Do I have to do anything else?

Comment: Why do you read with a `FileInputStream` instead of a `ObjectInputStream`? Did you check that both classes have the same `serialVersionUID`? And if that doesn't help, could you please past the whole exception and the recent code?

Comment: What do you mean by "copied". You should not copy it. You should use the exact same class.

Comment: my bad i use ObjectInputStream in another project too..i will edit question

Comment: by copy i mean copy paste class source code and class name..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not copy a class and the expect that it looks the same - the Java Compiler / the JVM notices the changes. Use **exactly the same class file**!!!

There are several versions to do so:

- Deliver Project1 with Project2 and set up your CLASSPATH
- Copy the class file in **the same package** to Project2
- attach a Jar to Project2 containing `MyClass`

And what you never should forgett: **Every `Serializable` should have a `serialVersionUID`** Eclipse automatically makes a warning - click on it and generate it. If you don't have Eclipse, use `serialver` from the JDK.
But don't forget: If your class changed so that old versions won't be interpretable by new versions, change the `serialversionUID`.

Comment: *Every Serializable should have a serialVersionUID*: no. That's just not true. Adding a serialVersionUID if you don't know what it is, how to use it, and how to make changes to your class and keep it backward compatible with serialized versions just adds noise to your code.

Comment: @JBNizet That's not true. I had the same JAR File with an `Object[Input|Output]Stream` in it running on Linux and Windows, and the files created on one OS didn't run on the other one with the Exception that those `serialVersionUID` didn't matched

Comment: Then you probably had 2 versions of the same class, but compiled by two different compilers. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/class.html#4100

Comment: @JBNizet No, it was really the same JAR File